# Mixing Like and Not Like in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to search a free text column that contain crime reports. I want to identify shot from a gun, but not blood shot eyes. What I wish is to exclude the term “shot” if it is saying blood shot, but still selected the row if shot is used elsewhere in the report. I believe the code below will exclude the row if “blood shot” is located, even if “shot” is mentioned multiple times.

```
(Narrative LIKE '%[^a-z]Shot[^a-z]%' and Narrative Not Like '%[^a-z]Blood?Shot[^a-z]%')
```

Is there a way exclude from the search terms if the term “shot” is near the term “Blood”. But not exclude the cell if the term “shot” shows up in another place in the report within the cell?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your patterns are not standard `LIKE` patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really not something you should be doing in base SQL -- databases are not very good are such string manipulation.  You probably want to look into the full text index capabilities on your database.

But I think the simplest method is:

```
where replace(lower(narrative), 'blood shot', '') like '%shot%'
```

That is, remove the "blood shot" from the string and then check.

You may still want to have delimiters around "shot".  Perhaps:

```
where concat(' ', replace(lower(narrative), 'blood shot', ''), ' ') like '%[^a-z]shot[^a-z]%'
```